# Pushing to new TableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am having an issue with pushing to a new TableView in objective C. Right now I have it to where in the first table it comes up with a list of animals, you press an animal, for example "Dog" and it then pushes to a new view and shows a list of dogs from an array. I want to then be able to select a specific dog and it say "Specs" about that specific dog.... I have tried to somewhat reverse engineer what I have done thus far, but I have been unsuccessful.

Right now I have the Main.storyboard, RootTableViewController, and SecondTableViewController...

I feel like I need to add a ThirdTableViewController to add my next TableView that will list the specs for the dog selected, but is that the only class I need to add?

**RootTableViewController.m**

```
#import "RootTableViewController.h"
#import "SecondTableViewController.h"

@interface RootTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation RootTableViewController
{
NSArray *animals;

}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

animals = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Dogs", @"Cats", @"Frogs", @"Gnats", nil];

// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [animals count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//makes table indentifier
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"AnimalCell";

//creates the cell
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier  forIndexPath:indexPath];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleDefault) reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [animals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before  navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showArrayDetail"])
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    SecondTableViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.animalName = [animals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    destViewController.title = destViewController.animalName;

}
}

@end
```

**RootTableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RootTableViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

**SecondTableViewController.m**

```
#import "RootTableViewController.h"
#import "SecondTableViewController.h"

@interface RootTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation RootTableViewController
{
NSArray *animals;

}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

animals = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Dogs", @"Cats", @"Frogs", @"Gnats", nil];

// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [animals count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//makes table indentifier
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"AnimalCell";

//creates the cell
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier  forIndexPath:indexPath];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleDefault) reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [animals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

**SecondTableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *animalName;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger *selectedIndex;

-(void)SelectedMasterItem:(NSInteger *)selected;

@end
```

**ThirdTableViewController.m**

```
#import "ThirdTableViewController.h"

@interface ThirdTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation ThirdTableViewController
{
NSArray *dogSpecs;
NSArray *catSpecs;
NSArray *frogSpecs;
NSArray *gnatSpecs;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

dogSpecs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Yellow", @"Black", @"Mean", @"Fast", @"Ugly", nil];
catSpecs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Smells", @"Hairy", @"Biter", @"Long", nil];
frogSpecs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Green", @"Yellow", @"Red", nil];
gnatSpecs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Crash", @"Annoying", @"Sad", nil];

// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if([_animalSpec isEqualToString:@"Dogs"])
{
    return [dogSpecs count];
}

else if([_animalSpec isEqualToString:@"Cats"])
{
    return [catSpecs count];
}

else if([_animalSpec isEqualToString:@"Frogs"])
{
    return [frogSpecs count];
}

else if([_animalSpec isEqualToString:@"Gnats"])
{
    return [gnatSpecs count];
}

return 0;

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//makes table indentifier
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Animal3Cell";

//creates the cell
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleDefault) reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

if([_animalSpec isEqualToString:@"Dogs"])
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [dogSpecs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

else if([_animalSpec isEqualToString:@"Cats"])
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [catSpecs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

else if([_animalSpec isEqualToString:@"Frogs"])
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [frogSpecs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

else if([_animalSpec isEqualToString:@"Gnats"])
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [gnatSpecs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

return cell;
}
@end
```

**ThirdTableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ThirdTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *animalSpec;

@end
```

I am sorry for all the code, I just wanted to post it all so maybe someone could understand what I was saying. I am sure that it is a beginners thing that I am just not understanding, if so, sorry for my ignorance.

Thanks

Comment: It isn't pushing to the third view that will list the animal specs

Comment: My guess is that it is in the cellForRowAtIndexPath and numberOfRowsInSection methods in ThirdTableViewController. Because the _animalSpec isn't equal to "Dogs", "Cats", etc....

Comment: You want push to a tableViewController right ?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure of the correct verbiage to use with Objective C since I am new to it. But basically I want to push to the ThirdViewController from the SecondViewController. I have the code for both posted, but I am sure the ThirdViewController code is wrong. It compiles, but does not do anything. In the SecondViewController there are a list of dogs, I want to be able to push a dog "Golden Retriever" and it go to a new view that lists that dogs specs....

Comment: The if clause of your prepareForSegue looks correct to go from the first controller to the second. But, the else clause should be in the second controller, not the first. If your doing 1 --> 2--> 3, then there's only one segue from each of the first two controllers. No need for an if-else.

Comment: @javaGeek : Please refere apple library for more information both beginers and experienced person  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> In first ViewController

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SecondTableViewController *secondViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondStoryBoardIdentifier"];
     secondViewController.selectedIndex =indexPath.row;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
}


> In Second ViewController

in .h file

@interface SecondTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger *selectedIndex;
-(void)SelectedMasterItem:(NSInteger *)selected;
@end

In .m file

@implementation SecondTableViewController
{
NSArray *dogs;
NSArray *cats;
NSArray *frogs;
NSArray *gnats;
NSMutableArray *arrayItems;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
arrayItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

dogSpecs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Yellow", @"Black", @"Mean", @"Fast", @"Ugly", nil];
catSpecs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Smells", @"Hairy", @"Biter", @"Long", nil];
frogSpecs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Green", @"Yellow", @"Red", nil];
gnatSpecs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Crash", @"Annoying", @"Sad", nil];

[self SelectedMasterItem:self.selectedIndex];

}

-(void)SelectedMasterItem:(NSInteger *)selected
{
    [arrayItems removeAllObjects];
    switch (selected) {

        case 0:
            arrayItems = [dogSpecs mutableCopy];
            break;

        case 1:
            arrayItems = [catSpecs mutableCopy];
            break;
        case 2:
            arrayItems = [frogSpecs mutableCopy];
            break;
         case 3:
            arrayItems = [gnatSpecs mutableCopy];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return arrayItems.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//makes table indentifier
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Animal3Cell";

//creates the cell
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

   if(!cell)
  {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleDefault)reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
  }
cell.textLabel.text =arrayItems[indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

Comment: When you say "first ViewController" is that my "RootTableViewController"? And which one of my classes are you referring to for the "Second ViewController" in your code?

Comment: I just posted my edited code with your answer in it. Does it look right? Also, I am getting an error with the word "selected" in the switch statement....

Comment: FirstviewControllre is your RootTableViewController

Comment: ' selected ' in a NSInteger, which is is property of secondViewcontroller, check that code itself.

Comment: Yeah, I've added the code above in my original post and it's still giving me that error with selected....

Comment: did you set property in 2ndVC , @property (nonatomic) NSInteger *selectedIndex; , in .h file ?

Comment: Should I add your code to what I already had? Or should I only have the code put up in my classes?